# Proguard returned with error code 1. in zxing

Tags: android, proguard

I activate proguard in my android project. When I compile and run in android, the apps works success. When I create signed apk, the process is error and show this error :

```
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find superclass or interface javax.swing.JFrame
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.maps.MapActivity
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find superclass or interface com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity: can't find referenced class com.example.tesbarcode.R$id
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity: can't find referenced class com.example.tesbarcode.R$id
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity: can't find referenced class com.example.tesbarcode.R
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.AffineTransform
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.AffineTransform
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics2D
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics2D
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.WritableRaster
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics2D
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.AffineTransform
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.BufferedImageLuminanceSource: can't find referenced class java.awt.Graphics2D
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.DecodeThread: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageIO
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.DecodeThread: can't find referenced method 'com.google.zxing.Result decode(com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap,java.util.Hashtable)' in class com.google.zxing.MultiFormatReader
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.DecodeThread: can't find referenced method 'com.google.zxing.Result[] decodeMultiple(com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap,java.util.Hashtable)' in class com.google.zxing.multi.GenericMultipleBarcodeReader
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.DecodeThread: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.DecodeThread: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.DecodeThread: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.DecodeThread: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.DecodeThread: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageIO
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.DecodeThread: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageIO
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.DecodeThread: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.DecodeThread: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.DecodeThread: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.DecodeThread: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.DecodeThread: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JFrame
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JLabel
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JLabel
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class java.awt.Dimension
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class java.awt.Dimension
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JPanel
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JPanel
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class java.awt.FlowLayout
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class java.awt.FlowLayout
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class java.awt.Container
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class java.awt.Container
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced method 'void setTitle(java.lang.String)' in class com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced method 'void setSize(int,int)' in class com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced method 'void setDefaultCloseOperation(int)' in class com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced method 'void setContentPane(java.awt.Container)' in class com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced method 'void setLocationRelativeTo(java.awt.Component)' in class com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced method 'void setVisible(boolean)' in class com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JFileChooser
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JFileChooser
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JFileChooser
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JFileChooser
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.ImageIcon
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.ImageIcon
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.Icon
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.Icon
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JLabel
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageIO
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JFrame
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class java.awt.Container
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.Icon
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageIO
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JLabel
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JTextArea
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class java.awt.Container
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.JFileChooser
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class javax.swing.Icon
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.GUIRunner: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageIO
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageIO
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter: can't find referenced class javax.imageio.ImageIO
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter: can't find referenced class java.awt.image.BufferedImage
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapActivity
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapActivity
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapActivity
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapActivity
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getString(int)' in class com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced method 'android.content.res.Resources getResources()' in class com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapActivity
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapActivity
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced method 'void setContentView(int)' in class com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced method 'android.content.Intent getIntent()' in class com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapActivity
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced method 'android.view.View findViewById(int)' in class com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced method 'void showDialog(int)' in class com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapView
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapView
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapView
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$1: can't find referenced method 'void finish()' in class com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$LocationThread$1: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$LocationThread$1: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$LocationThread$1: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapView
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$LocationThread$1: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapView
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$LocationThread$1: can't find referenced method 'int getLatSpanE6()' in class com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$LocationThread$1: can't find referenced method 'int getLonSpanE6()' in class com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$LocationThread$1: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapController
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$LocationThread$1: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapController
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$LocationThread$1: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$LocationThread$1: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$LocationThread$1: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapController
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$LocationThread$1: can't find referenced method 'void dismissDialog(int)' in class com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$LocationThread$1: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$MapTask: can't find referenced method 'android.content.res.Resources getResources()' in class com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$MapTask: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapView
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$MapTask: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapView
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$MapTask: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$MapTask: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$MapTask: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.MerchantTabStores$MapTask: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable boundCenterBottom(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' in class com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced method 'void populate()' in class com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapView
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapView
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint
com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: com.intouch.dev.alacards.StoreItemizedOverlay: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: there were 145 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] Warning: there were 21 unresolved references to program class members.
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2015-09-07 11:04:51 - AlacardsIndonesiaDev]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

How to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: I'm having issues with proguard and zxing library. Have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppress the warnings with adding these lines to your proguard config file:

```
-dontwarn com.google.zxing.client.**
-dontwarn com.intouch.dev.alacards.**
```

Comment: if I use -dontwarn com.google.zxing.client.**, when scan qr code, the apps has stopped and error